# One day earlier than Earliest admission date | F1 OPT application

Tags: visas, f1-visas

I am on F1 and applying for OPT. I was misadvised by our school International Office and arrived 1 day earlier than the Earliest admission date stated on my I-20. I was admitted into the US after showing the CBP officer a letter of support from the International Office.

**The problem is on my I-94 the Most Recent Date of Entry is 1 day before the Earliest admission date stated on my I-20.**

**Will that cause problem for my OPT application? And what should I do?**

Thank you!